# Find all instances of word occurring in a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, debian

Using bash I was wondering how I can find all instances of a word which starts with text, store it as a variable and print it out.

For example if this was my file

**test.conf**

```
$temp_test
test
$1234_$temp
$temp_234
```

My output would be as follows:

```
   $temp_test
   $temp_234
```

Can anyone tell me how this might be possible? This is the closest I could get so far.

```
while read NAME
do
    echo "$NAME"
done < test.conf
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use grep with right regex:

```
grep '^ *$temp' test.conf
$temp_test
$temp_234
```

**UPDATE:** As per comments:

```
while read -r l; do
   echo "$l"
done < <(sed -n '/^ *$temp_/s/^ *\$temp_//p' t.conf)

test
234
```

Comment: I do need to store the variables rather than just print it each time, because I want to manipulate the variable. Is there a way to do some sort of loop where I add it into a variable and echo it? Storing it in a variable will allow me to manipulate it, in my case, grab what ever is after $temp_ and also store that in a variable.

Comment: Sure you can loop the grep's output like this: **`while read -r l; do echo "$l"; done < <(grep '^ *$temp' t.conf)`**