# Make SED command work for any variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, debian

**deploy.sh**

```
USERNAME="Tom"
PASSWORD="abc123"
FILE="config.conf"
sed -i "s/\PLACEHOLDER_USERNAME/$USERNAME/g" $FILE
sed -i "s/\PLACEHOLDER_PASSWORD/$PASSWORD/g" $FILE
```

**config.conf**

```
deloy="PLACEHOLDER_USERNAME"
pass="PLACEHOLDER_PASSWORD"
```

This file puts my variables defined in deploy into my config file. I can't source the file so I want put my variables in this way.

**Question**

I want a command that is generic to work for *all placeholder variables* using some sort of while loop rather than needing one command per variable. This means any term starting with placeholder_ in the file will try to be replaced with the value of the variable defined already in deploy.sh

All variables should be set and not empty. I guess if there is the ability to print a warning if it can't find the variable that would be good but it isn't mandatory for this.

Comment: same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20241748/run-through-file-and-parse-placeholder-variables

Comment: Oh not again, didn't I already answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20240668/548225

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find all instances of word occurring in a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20240627/find-all-instances-of-word-occurring-in-a-file)

Comment: The first one doesn't work for generic examples and the second one find's all instances but doesn't do any replacement. They are helping me to understand but they are not at all the same question.

Comment: I made the question clearer in my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, use shell code to write a `sed` script and then use `sed -i .bak -f sed.script config.conf` to apply it:

```
trap "rm -f sed.script; exit 1" 0 1 2 3 13 15

for var in USERNAME PASSWORD
do
    echo "s/PLACEHOLDER_$var/${!var}/"
done > sed.script

sed -i .bak -f sed.script config.conf

rm -f sed.script
trap 0
```

The main 'tricks' here are:

1. knowing that `${!var}` expands to the value of the variable named by `$var`, and
2. knowing that `sed` will take a script full of commands via `-f sed.script`, and
3. knowing how to use `trap` to ensure temporary files are cleaned up.

You could also use `sed -e "s/.../.../" -e "s/.../.../" -i .bak config.conf` too, but the script file is easier, I think, especially if you have more than 2 values to substitute. If you want to go down this route, use a `bash` array to hold the arguments to `sed`. A more careful script would use at least `$$` in the script file name, or use `mktemp` to create the temporary file.

---

#### Revised answer

> The trouble is, although much closer to being generic, it is still not generic since I have to manually put in what variables I want to change. Can it not be more like "for each placeholder_, find the variable in `deploy.sh` and add that variable, so it can work for any number of variables.

So, find what the variables are in the configuration file, then apply the techniques of the previous answer to solve that problem:

```
trap "rm -f $tmp; exit 1" 0 1 2 3 13 15

for file in "$@"
do

    for var in $(sed 's/.*PLACEHOLDER_\([A-Z0-9_]*\).*/\1/' "$file")
    do
        value="${!var}"
        [ -z "$value" ] && { echo "$0: variable $var not set for $file" >&2; exit 1; }
        echo "s/PLACEHOLDER_$var/$value/"
    done > $tmp

    sed -i .bak -f $tmp "$file"

    rm -f $tmp

done

trap 0
```

This code still pulls the values from the environment. You need to clarify what is required if you want to extract the settings from the shell script, but it can be done — the script will have to be sufficiently self-aware to find its source so it can search it for the names. But the basics are in this answer; the rest is a question of tinkering until it does what you need.

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer. The trouble is, although much closer to being generic, it is still not generic since I have to manually put in what variables I want to change. Can it not be more like "for each placeholder_, find the variable in deploy.sh and add that variable, so it can work for any number of variables.

Comment: Please update the question with the extra information from your comment. Will your environment always have all the variables set? What should the script do if a required variable is not set? Can a variable ever be empty?

Comment: Updated as per your request, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/ksh
TemplateFile=$1
SourceData=$2

(sed 's/.*/#V0r:PLACEHOLDER_&:r0V#/' ${SourceData}; cat ${TemplateFile}) | sed -n "

s/$/²/
H

$  {
   x
   s/^\(\n *\)*//
# also reset t flag
   t varxs

:varxs
   s/^#V0r:\([a-zA-Z0-9_]\{1,\}\)=\([^²]*\):r0V#²\(\n.*\)\"\1\"/#V0r:\1=\2:r0V#²\3\2/
   t varxs

# clean the line when no more occurance in text
   s/^[^²]*:r0V#²\n//

# and next
   t varxs


# clean the  marker
   s/²\(\n\)/\1/g
   s/²$//

# display the result
   p
   }
"
```

call like this: `YourScript.ksh YourTemplateFile YourDataSourceFile` where:

- YourTemplateFile is the file that contain the structure with generic value like `deloy="PLACEHOLDER_USERNAME"`
- YourDataSourceFile is the file that contain all the peer Generic value = specific value like `USERNAME="Tom"`